# Google Calendar in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, calendar

How can I open my Google Calendar in Ubuntu 20.04?

Three years ago, on another computer with Ubuntu 18.04, someone else helped me by putting a Link to Google Calendar shortcut on the desktop. I don't know how they did it.

At first, clicking on that desktop link opened the calendar. For the past year or so, it opens to a sign in request which opens the calendar. I'm typing this now on that 18.04 machine, since I'm still setting up the one with the new OS. When I clicked on the link provided here by heynnema, it instantly opened my calendar.

Is there a way to make that link a shortcut on the 20.04 desktop? One of the first things I did after booting up Focal was to add Google to my online accounts, and I have all its apps enabled, including the calendar, but I don't see how to open them.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This will make it easier to not provide an answer you don’t need 

Comment: Go to https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r?pli=1

Comment: If you add Google to your online accounts, then you should be able to access your Google calendar from GNOME's built in calendar app (not a link to website, just all events from your Google calendar should appear in GNOME calendar app and you should be able to view/add/modify them directly in the app).

Comment: I'd like to move away from Google, but its calendar has features I haven't found anywhere else. I'd like to have a desktop link to it like on my 18.04 computer.

Answer (score 2):

GNOME Calendar can sync Online Accounts like Google.

1. Install GNOME Calendar with the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-calendar
   ```
2. Add the Google Account in Settings → *Online Accounts* (You can add it from GNOME Calendar as well):

   [image: System Settings -> Online Accounts]
3. Then enable the Google Account checkbox in GNOME Calendar:

   [image: GNOME Calendar]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you had was a 'windowed' shortcut

To do this (In Chrome):

1. Open the webpage and click the three dots on the top right
2. Choose "More tools"
3. Choose "Create Shortcut..."
4. Name the shorcut (e.g. "Google Calendar"), and make sure to select "Open as window"

Now you can find "Google Calendar" in your apps, and you can add it to your favorites if you want. (And as an added bonus, the icon is even set correctly).

You can do this for any website, but I find it helpful for most Google apps (Gmail, Calendar, Drive, etc.)

Comment: On my 20.04 computer, when I open Chrome's context menu and click on "More tools", "Create shortcut" is greyed-out and unresponsive.

Answer (score -3):

You can use [Calendar Indicator](https://github.com/atareao/calendar-indicator) instead.

To download it, type these lines in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt update
sudo apt install calendar-indicator
```

Comment: Google blocked this app, saying it is unsafe.

Comment: From the [discussion and comments on Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20069/1165986), it seems that this extension does not work if you have multi-factor authentication (a.k.a. 2FA) enabled on your Google account.  There multiple issue reports on this on the project's Github repo ([example](https://github.com/atareao/calendar-indicator/issues/7)), but (currently) it hasn't seen a source commit (other than the readme) in 3 years or so.  Thanks to @andrew.46 for the research.

Comment: My comment on Jul 25 was inaccurate. What Google indicated was that the app may not be secure. This prompted me to ask in Meta about unsafe downloads. (https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20069/1165986) I got valuable advice there about downloading in general, and also information specifically about the Calendar Indicator which prompted the question.